# ggplot display data table bottom of graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to display a data table at the bottom of the graph similar to this:

[image: Sample Graph]

I have been trying the code in [this](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/ggplot2-labelling-data-series-and-adding-a-data-table/) post but it does not run in my RStudio version 1.1.383.

The dataframe for the graph is:

```
Pay.Quartiles = rep(c("lower", "lower.mid", "upper.mid", "upper"),2)
Gender = rep (c("Female", "Male"), each = 4)
Percentage = c(65.1,57.5,47.4, 41.3, 34.9, 42.5, 52.6, 58.7)

df = data.frame (Pay.Quartiles, Gender, Percentage)
```

Comment: The RStudio version is somewhat irrelevant (the versions of R & ggplot2 are likely more important). Ideally, you'd include the code you tried with the post so folks who might want to answer can use the same code you tried (humans are imperfect and you may have transcribed the code errantly) and not have to hit another site to try to render assistance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of some data wrangling (to get better labels) and faceting with some strip placement tweaks should do the trick:

```
library(hrbrthemes) # gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/hrbrthemes or github
library(ggplot2)

Pay.Quartiles <-  rep(c("Lower", "Lower Middle", "Upper Middle", "Upper"), 2)
Gender <-  rep(c("Female", "Male"), each = 4)
Percentage <-  c(65.1,57.5,47.4, 41.3, 34.9, 42.5, 52.6, 58.7)/100

xdf <- data.frame (Pay.Quartiles, Gender, Percentage, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

xdf$lab <- sprintf("%s\n%s", Gender, scales::percent(Percentage))

ggplot(xdf) +
  geom_col(
    aes(lab, Percentage, fill = Gender), 
    width = 0.5, show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  facet_wrap(
    ~Pay.Quartiles, scales = "free_x", nrow = 1, strip.position = "bottom"
  ) +
  hrbrthemes::scale_y_percent() +
  hrbrthemes::scale_fill_ipsum() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum_rc(grid = "Y") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside") +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(hjust=0.5)) +
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0.33, "lines"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much.  I didn't know the package "hrbrthemes". This works great!